# Can someone fix this problem with cloth physics?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to re-create this scene from a youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUf9VltV4Cc). There are two cubes in the scene (the bed and mattress). The cloth is supposed to fall on the mattress but it falls through it on the second cube (the bed). Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? The file can be accessed at this link (https://gofile.io/?c=1j2Icj)
Also, the cloth also acts strange when I run the animation.
I'd appreciate if someone can help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you did not set the second cube to "Collision". You can do this by going to the Physics tab and selecting *Collision*. You can continue by playing with the collision settings and seeing what works for you.